# Spring Boot - Change Locale on click

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am using SpringBoot for my web application and I want to bind 2 buttons to 2 different languages, but I dont know how to do it right.

I have tried to do this but it doesn't work.

```
@RequestMapping("/language")
public class LanguageController {

    @RequestMapping("esp")
    public String setEsp(SessionLocaleResolver session)
    {
        Locale esp = new Locale("es_ES" );
        session.setDefaultLocale(esp);
        return "index";
    }

    @RequestMapping("eng")
    public String setEng(SessionLocaleResolver session)
    {
        session.setDefaultLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
        return "index";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are **several errors** in your current setup:

1. `SessionLocaleResolver` is **not** a supported handler method argument - therefore your current code should result in a `NullpointerException` when calling any of the handler methods. In order to get access to `SessionLocaleResolver` you have to set it up in your Spring Boot `Application.java`.
2. Once `SessionLocaleResolver` can be autowired into your Controller, you should call `setLocale` rather than `setDefaultLocale` and things should start working.
3. Since changing `Locale` is a common use case, Spring provides  the [LocaleChangeInterceptor](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/i18n/LocaleChangeInterceptor.html) that **eliminates the need for custom logic** and keeps your handler methods clean.

For example code of how to set this up in Spring Boot check [this](http://justinrodenbostel.com/2014/05/13/part-4-internationalization-in-spring-boot/).

Comment: I wouldn't hard code the SessionLocaleResolver implementation directly. Use `RequestContextUtils.getLocaleResolver(request)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at LocaleChangeInterceptor (https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-localeresolver-interceptor)

If enabled, simply add url parameter `locale=...` to any request and that locale will be used then.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
RequestContextUtils.getLocaleResolver(request).setLocale(request, response, locale);
```